# giving a movie texture to lamp (spot) in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, lighting

im currently making an underwater scene which has caustic lighting in it, so i prepare the objects (lamp, 2 planes, one with ocean modifier) and give movie texture to the lamp and... it doesnt work.

i know how to do this in blender render, in fact it just works like the same as i did in cycles render : give a movie texture to the spot lamp and it works. but it looks like cycles doesnt work the same as blender render.

here's what it looks like when i give texture to spot lamp in cycles

i've connected a texture coordinate : reflection node to the movie texture
(edited : it works and it animated, i tried rendering it out to see the light and it animated)

Comment: In the Image Texture *Properties* rollout the source field is empty and it writes that it can't load the file. Did you make sure to load in the movie in Blender properly ? Also use some vector input for the movie.

Comment: @MrZak thanks for the suggestion, it works after i connected it with vector mapping node, the cycles render cant animate it realtime, but it played when i rendered it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might not be exactly what you need but could help.
The set up is for a videomapping.
Create a spot lamp, you might need to crank it up very high (Like VERY high, use filminc blender if needed)Put a plane between the spot lamp and the surface that needs to capture the projection. Nodes for the plane

[image: Nodes for the plane]

animate the offset if it is a video file